# How do I make the canvas move around a position or sprite?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I made the snake game following a tutorial, here's the code for it.
https://github.com/maxwihlborg/youtube-tutorials/blob/master/snake/index.html

I was wondering how to make the canvas move around the snake while the head of the snake stays in the same position. Could I do this by modifying the code I already have or would it have to be coded in a completely different way?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Nice job on your snake game, works well. I hate when people ask why you want to do what you want to do, but I am going to in this case. WHY?! It seems incredibly silly to me.

Comment: I'm trying to make a game similar to agario but with snakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll have to move your snake in the snake-like "chain-slither":

1. `pop` to take off the tail.
2. `unshift` to add a new head.

And then use Lee Presswood's idea of "unmoving" all the snake pieces so the snake head is always at the same coordinate on the canvas.

Finally, to give the appearance of moving, you can offset a canvas background by the amount that the snake would have moved.

Here's a proof-of-concept:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var size=15;

var snake=[];
snake.push({x:10,y:10});
snake.push({x:9,y:10});
snake.push({x:8,y:10});
snake.push({x:8,y:11});
snake.push({x:8,y:12});
snake.push({x:8,y:13});
snake.push({x:7,y:13});
snake.push({x:6,y:13});
snake.push({x:5,y:13});

var offX=-100;
var offY=-100;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
  draw();
}
img.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/snakeBackground.jpg';


function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.drawImage(img,offX,offY);
  for(var i=0;i<snake.length;i++){
    if(i==0){
      ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
      ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x*size,snake[i].y*size,size,size);
      ctx.strokeRect(snake[i].x*size,snake[i].y*size,size,size);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(snake[i].x*size+size/2,snake[i].y*size+size/2,3,0,Math.PI*2);
      ctx.fillStyle='red';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
    }else if(i==snake.length-1){
      ctx.fillStyle='mediumBlue';
      ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x*size,snake[i].y*size,size,size);
      ctx.strokeRect(snake[i].x*size,snake[i].y*size,size,size);
    }else{
      ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
      ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x*size,snake[i].y*size,size,size);
      ctx.strokeRect(snake[i].x*size,snake[i].y*size,size,size);
    }
  }
}


$('#left').click(function(){ move(-1,0); });
$('#right').click(function(){ move(1,0); });
$('#up').click(function(){ move(0,-1); });
$('#down').click(function(){ move(0,1); });


function move(dx,dy){
  var x=snake[0].x+dx*size;
  var y=snake[0].y+dy*size;
  offX-=dx*size;
  offY-=dy*size;

  var hit=false;
  for(var i=0;i<snake.length;i++){        
    if(snake[i].x==x && snake[i].y==y){ hit=true; }
  }

  if(!hit){
    snake.pop();
    snake.unshift({x:snake[0].x+dx,y:snake[0].y+dy});
    for(var i=0;i<snake.length;i++){
      snake[i].x-=dx;
      snake[i].y-=dy;
    }
    draw();
  }
}
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Use the buttons to move the snake on the dirt trail.</h4>
<button id='left'>Left</button>
<button id='right'>Right</button>
<button id='up'>Up</button>
<button id='down'>Down</button>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an odd request, but I'll bite.

Let's say you want your snake to move by 25 pixels left. With a stationary camera, you would just do `snake_position.x -= 25` and everything would work out for us.

We're talking about moving the actual canvas, though. This is the exact opposite of our last situation. Rather than moving the snake and keeping the canvas stationary, we're moving the canvas and keeping the snake stationary. Because we're talking opposite's, we're going to move our canvas to the right `canvas_position.x += 25` to create the illusion of our snake moving to the left.

It's a weird concept, but try to picture a video camera. Panning to the right makes the object on the screen leave off the right side of the screen. They're not actually moving, but they appear to be. It's the same concept here.